# Как сделать регулярное выражение для отрезка в script

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

**Добрый вечер, не могу понять, как сделать регулярное выражение для данного отрезк**а:

[image: отрезок из scripta]

**Я ввел регулярное выражение для поиска ID канала в этом же скрипте**

```
channel_id = re.findall(r'[\'\"]CHANNEL_ID[\'\"]\s*\:\s*[\'\"]([^\'\"]*)[\'\"]',script.text, flags=re.I)
```

**Он правильно выводит ID канала**

[image: вывод]

**А такое же выражение для поиска кол-ва подписчиков показывает мне None**

```
subs = re.findall(r'[\'\"]subscriberCount[\'\"]\s*\:\s*[\'\"]([^\'\"]*)[\'\"]',script.text, flags=re.I)
```

**Как быть?**

Comment: Приводите код в виде текста, пожалуйста, а не только копии экрана.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша регулярка требует чтобы были пробельные символы слева и справа от ":", а их там нет.
Вот тут:

```
['"]subscriberCount['"]\s*:\s*
```

Хотя вместо этого лучше выдернуть и отпарсить весь json.

PS: В помощь вам [Регулярка проверки валидного json](https://regex101.com/library/tA9pM8)

Comment: не работает, инвалид выводит